# Why won't the correct median of the array get printed?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

Since the length of the array's even, we must add 12 + 8 = 20 and then divide that by two.  20 / 2 = 10.  But why's it printing out 30 in console?  Even if I exclude `Arrays.sort(a);`, it still prints 30.

It's supposed to print 10.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void solution(int[] a) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int median = 0;

    if(a.length % 2 != 0) {
        median = a[(a.length - 1) / 2];
    } else {
        median = (a[(a.length / 2)] + a[(a.length - 1 / 2) - 1]) / 2;
    } 
    System.out.println(median);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = {5,9,8,12,19,48};
    solution(a);
}
```

Comment: why `a.length - 1 / 2`? why `(a.length - 1 / 2) - 1`?

Comment: `(a.length - 1 / 2)` will be `(a.length - 0)` because of operator precedence

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I guess that's what I was struggling with trying to add them properly.

Comment: I would expect `(a.length / 2) - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `median = (a[(a.length / 2) - 1] + a[(a.length / 2)]) / 2;`